# xml missing errors in jobtracker logs

Tags: hadoop

i see many of these errors in our hadoop jobtracker logs, can anyone shed some light about this ?
cluster is CDH4.2 with single jobtracker and MRV1.
this is the error:

```
2014-05-13 22:43:40,987 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskInProgress: Error from attempt_201405081738_82268_m_000016_0: Error initializing attempt_201405081738_82268_m_000016_0:
org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: Could not find taskTracker/hive-primary/jobcache/job_201405081738_82268/job.xml in any of the configured local directories
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.getLocalPathToRead(LocalDirAllocator.java:445)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.getLocalPathToRead(LocalDirAllocator.java:164)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.initializeJob(TaskTracker.java:1438)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.localizeJob(TaskTracker.java:1310)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.startNewTask(TaskTracker.java:2727)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker$TaskLauncher.run(TaskTracker.java:2691)

2014-05-13 22:43:40,988 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskStatus: Trying to set finish time for task attempt_201405081738_82268_m_000016_0 when no start time is set, stackTrace is : java.lang.Exception
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskStatus.setFinishTime(TaskStatus.java:185)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskInProgress.incompleteSubTask(TaskInProgress.java:670)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress.failedTask(JobInProgress.java:2893)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress.updateTaskStatus(JobInProgress.java:1178)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.updateTaskStatuses(JobTracker.java:4305)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.processHeartbeat(JobTracker.java:3232)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.heartbeat(JobTracker.java:2931)
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
  at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Server$WritableRpcInvoker.call(WritableRpcEngine.java:474)
  at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1002)
  at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1695)
  at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1691)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
  at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
  at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1689)
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This thread](https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/DISTRO-485) from Clouder's bug tracker may help.

Comment: 10x, this looks like my problem, although i cannot test it right now. would give it +1 but i don't have enough reputation.